# Progress bar not setting correct width

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var ehealth = + $('#enemyHealth').text(); // this shows 100

    $('.enemy-bar').css('width', function(index, value){
        return ehealth - userDmg+"%"; // userDmg can be anything between 0-500
     });
```

Problem is that if `userDmg` is 50 or more than 50 the `enemy-bar` width always sets to 0%. How it's possible to solve this ?

Comment: I understand what you want. First you should have also full health value. Then use  `return ((ehealth-userDmg)/fullHeath)*100+"%";`

Answer (score 0):

try to parse ehealth to integer first, i think type of data is string, its reason cant to calculate

```
var ehealth = parseInt(ehealth);
return ((ehealth - userDmg)/fullHeath)*100+"%";
```